# Swift 3 reference type and memory management

Tags: c++, swift, memory-leaks, swift3

I've studied that Class type is reference type in Swift.

So, for example, I have following statements:

```
class Rectangle {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
}

var a = Rectangle(x: 10, y: 10)
var b = Rectangle(x: 30, y: 30)
// (a.x, a.y) == (10, 10) and (b.x, b.y) == (30, 30)

b = a
b.x = 50
b.y = 50
// (a.x, a.y) == (50, 50) due to both instance a and b
// refer to the same piece in the memory
```

I think this behavior is similar to C++'s pointer, for example:

```
SomeDefinedClass *ptrA = new SomeDefinedClass(10, 10);
SomeDefinedClass *ptrB = new SomeDefinedClass(30, 30);
// (ptrA->x, ptrA->y) == (10, 10)
// (ptrB->x, ptrB->y) == (30, 30)

ptrB = ptrA;
ptrB->x = 50;
ptrB->y = 50;
// (ptrA->x, ptrA->y) == (50, 50) due to both ptrA and ptrB
// point to the same object in the memory
```

But in C++, this kind of pointer assignment (ptrB = ptrA) can cause
memory leak without

```
delete ptrB;
```

before

```
ptrB = ptrA;
```

The tutorial I studied didn't mention this,
but I think Swift can do some behavior like "delete ptrB;" automatically, 
so I don't need to handle this, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift uses a technique called Automatic Reference Counting(ARC) which keeps track of number of references an object currently has and deallocate the memory when the count reaches to zero. When you do `b = a` in swift, the reference count of old `b` reaches to zero, assuming there is no other reference to it. Swift sees that it is zero and delete it. That's why you don't need to `delete` yourself in swift. You can learn more about ARC from [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/134411/arc-memory-management-swift).

If you would like to compare it with C++, then, No, it doesn't work like raw pointers. Instead it works more like C++11's smart pointer `std::shared_ptr`.